# How do you check if string is in either of 2 scripts javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I understand that the following checks for greek unicode script 
`/\p{Script=Greek}/u.test("α")`
But is it possible to check is the script is either of 2/3 options?

I tried to do

`/\p{Script=Greek|Latin}/u.test("α")`,
 `/\p{Script=Greek}|{Script=Latin}/u.test("α")`

But these don't seem to be working.

Comment: Try adding `\p` to the second option as well `/\p{Script=Greek}|\p{Script=Latin}/u.test("α")`

Comment: [Use Perl](http://p3rl.org/recharclass#Extended-Bracketed-Character-Classes) when you don't want to be disappointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `test` method of a regular expression returns a boolean, so the simplest solution is just to use two such statements, and then combine the booleans they return.

If you want to combine two boolean values in Javascript, you can either use the `&&` ("and") or `||` ("or") operators.  In your case you want to use `||`:

```
const candidate = "α";
const isGreekOrLatin = /\p{Script=Greek}/u.test(candidate) ||
                       /\p{Script=Latin}/u.test(candidate);
```